# Am I allowed to pass multiple arguments to the Ant compilerarg element?

Tags: java, ant

In Ant, am I alllowed to do something like this:

```
<compilerarg value= "-Xlint:deprecation,unchecked" />
```

i.e, I  want to pass both `-Xlint:deprecation` and `-Xlint:unchecked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page describes the proper way to use compilerarg elements: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

You can either do multiple nested elements like this:

```
<compilerarg value= "-Xlint:deprecation" />
<compilerarg value= "-Xlint:unchecked" />
```

Or use the line attribute instead of value:

```
<compilerarg line= "-Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked" />
```